# How do I get the fullest data record from a data set in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return a set of records that contain the most amount of data in the fields specified
The primary key for the table is a license key so a user can register multiple licenses - there is no need for a user account, so we can't have a one to many relationship of a single user account to many licences (unfortunatley!)

Sometimes the user will give us a minimal amount of info. Eg firstname, lastname, email. Sometimes they give us more. a FacebookID and Date of Birth.

I've tried grouping on the email address and doing order by clauses on the FBID as in the query below, but I'm struggling with my knowledge of MySQL and I'm now wondering if it's even possible!?

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, email, FBID, DOB
FROM users
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY FBID IS NULL;
```

I want to extract the fullest amount of data from a set always grouping on email address:

```
John, Smith, john@smith.com, NULL, NULL
John, Smith, john@smith.com, 123456, NULL
John, Smith, john@smith.com, NULL, '1/1/1990'
Fred, Jones, fred@jones.com, NULL, NULL
```

What I want to return:

```
John, Smith, john@smith.com, 123456, '1/1/1990'
Fred, Jones, fred@jones.com, NULL, NULL
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. First thing I do not get is those three rows for the same user. Usually the `email` would be unique key to keep the data more consistent.

Comment: I know, but as I said, there is no concept of a user account here. It's just a small amount of data against a single license key as when it was built they didn't think that users would buy more than one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using aggreagtion function for extact the values when are not null

```
  select  firstname, lastname, email, max(FBID), max(DOB)
  from  users
  group by firstname, lastname, email
  order by  firstname, lastname, email
```

Comment: damn it, you beat me hahaha

Comment: [Here's my Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0abd3b/12), feel free to use it in your answer

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been puzzling this all day! Thanks again for the help!